# Service action does not work when defined in string.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-service

I am facing one weired problem. I have defined my service action in `string.xml` and using the same in manifest like this:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="@string/my_service_action" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Also while starting the service I am starting like this:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getResources().getString(R.string.my_service_action));
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem.

If I hard code the same value of action, it works perfectly fine. After some hit n try I found that it doesn't work only when used in manifest file(e.g. hard code the action value in java code only not manifest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can use string reference as action string for service. It must a concrete string value. As per javadoc:

> **android:name** The name of an action that is handled, using the Java-style   naming
>   convention. [string]

For example:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.demo.service.MY_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and then you should use it as:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.demo.service.MY_SERVICE");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: Hi Waqas. Thanks for reply but your answer says action should be a concrete string value but I did not see the same in Java-doc. Also manifest uses some other attributes in manifest like what I am doing. For example android:lable="@string/app_name". So the question is why it is not working for action attribute?

Comment: If you mouse over label, it would say `A user-legible name for the given item. [string, reference]` which means it allows you to set either **String** or **Reference** of string. So actually its telling you itself what it requires. Now if you look the one I've posted, it only says **String** which means you cant use reference. You can verify this yourself in manifest :)